# Angular How to control a directive from a service?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to do a Service that control a directive.

So the purpose is to use the Service in a Controller to ask the Directive to do something.

eg. `SomeService.tellSomething('ok');` will trigger the directive with a param

I know that we can use `$rootScope.$broadcast` to send/trigger event but I honestly don't know if it is a good practice...

Any advices/techniques ?

Comment: You can inject `SomeService` into directive and make it do something there.

Comment: Thank you @dfsq but the purpose is to use the service to control the directive.

Comment: I understand. You probably misunderstand me. I'm saying that it's up to you what do do with the service in directive. you can set up a watcher inside reacting to service state changes, or you can implement pub/sub mechanism (I would go with this approach).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pub/sub pattern for this. For example:

Add a `subscribeToTellsomething` method to your service. Inject your service into directive as a dependency, and make your directive subscribe to it when it's linked (link method). Now make service publish something to all subscribers when `tellSomething` method is called.

Comment: I will look after that. But at first look, it seems going to the right direction. About that, it is a better practice than using event ?

Comment: I have read some good examplse about PubSub pattern in AngularJS. I think this is definitely the better solution. There, some read about that: [Angular PubSub Pattern](http://scriptogr.am/pploug/post/communication-in-angular-using-the-pubsub-pattern) and [Angular Simple PubSub](https://gist.github.com/floatingmonkey/3384419)

Comment: I am not sure why it's better then $broadcast, why implement your own when it's already there? + angular will handle unsubscribing when scopes are destroyed.

Comment: Few reasons. `$broadcast` has to traverse through whole scope tree on the page (which can get huge). Second, your service starts to depend on `framework` itself, which should generally be avoided if you don't have to do it. Third, it's a lot harder to debug and for someone working on your code later to find what depends on what.

Comment: Well, it just fit more my purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the watch pattern for this, the pub/sub method is also viable, but it's more work, and I think $broadcast is actually using the same pattern behind the scenes, but don't quote me on that.

The watch approach is having something like this:

```
MyService.getSomething = function() 
    {
      return something;
    }
```

in your directive:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
      return MyService.getSomething();
     }, function(newSomething) {
         //do your thing
     });
```

Comment: Interesting ! I didn't know that we can `$watch` a method result's. I think the PubSub pattern is better for my case because it let me pass some args easily and allow me to structural communication between other services/directives/controllers.

Comment: Having many of these could slow down your performance significantly, as  $watch callback will be called **lots** of times during each `$digest` cycle.

Comment: ofc, but tbh, most of the times the watch cycle is really not an issue when you are just returning a reference it's np to get up to thousands of watches. There is no reason to be afraid of it.